# Iterate_level after SetRectangle in tesseract Python wrapper

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

I have an image with few lines of japanese Kanji for which I am trying modifying the boxes boundes before to iterate over and get the font and its attributes.

I could check that Pyplot is displaying the boxes correctly. Also the text is correctly returned if I remove the loop which setRectangle.

My function is as below:

```
def font_attr(resized):


   img = resized
    image = Image.fromarray(img)

    with PyTessBaseAPI(path='C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\fast_format_assist\\tessdata\\', lang='jpn+msp+hgp', oem=0, psm=3) as api:
        api.SetImage(image)
        
        boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
        delta = 5 

        image_array = np.array(image)
        for box in boxes:
            print(box)
            box = box[1]
            x, y, w, h = box['x'] - delta, box['y'] - delta, box['w'] + 2 * delta, box['h'] + 2 * delta
            cv2.line(image_array, (x, y), (x + w, y), (0, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image_array, (x, y), (x, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image_array, (x + w, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image_array, (x, y + h), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        plt.imshow(image_array)
        plt.show()

        for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
             print(i,  (im, box, _, _))
             api.SetRectangle(box['x'] - delta, box['y'] - delta, box['w'] + 2 * delta, box['h'] + 2 * delta) 

        api.Recognize()
        ri = api.GetIterator()
        font = []
        attributes = []
        for r in iterate_level(ri, RIL.BLOCK):
            symbol = r.GetUTF8Text(RIL.BLOCK)
            conf = r.Confidence(RIL.BLOCK)
            symbol = symbol.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ', '')
            word_attributes = r.WordFontAttributes()
            if not symbol:
                continue
            else:
                font.append([symbol, 'confidence: ',conf])
                attributes.append(word_attributes)
            
            return font, attributes
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\m1\fast_format_assist\font_reader.py", line 338, in <module>
    attr = font_attr(resized)
  File "c:\Users\m1\fast_format_assist\font_reader.py", line 216, in font_attr
    symbol = r.GetUTF8Text(RIL.TEXTLINE)
  File "tesserocr.pyx", line 820, in tesserocr._tesserocr.PyLTRResultIterator.GetUTF8Text
RuntimeError: No text returned
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better you go with easyocr for this case.

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim'],gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('5.png')
for detection in result:
    print(detection)
```

the result is,

```
([[0, 0], [384, 0], [384, 70], [0, 70]], '二九办一番目', 0.04030529339493764)
([[0, 75], [381, 75], [381, 155], [0, 155]], '二九加二番目', 0.06939456423064959)
([[0, 164], [380, 164], [380, 242], [0, 242]], '二九|4别0去', 0.02179895938530989)
([[0, 249], [385, 249], [385, 335], [0, 335]], '二九|寸危害学', 0.01723975047661578)
([[0, 335], [385, 335], [385, 421], [0, 421]], '二九(丈著盥目', 0.004155675980245961)
([[0, 424], [382, 424], [382, 499], [0, 499]], '二札|击六番目', 0.022589517592635434)
```

You can install easyocr by `pip install easyocr`